# Clip content using images

Tags: godot4

[image]

How can i prevent that image go out of container (border). My border is a image, inserted as texture of sprite.

My structure:

[image]

Then i load the image with a script:
[image]

I already tried use a panel with a corder radius, and the bg color stay fit, but the image keeps overlapping.
Tried shaders and textures as well..